# Codeigniter - mod_rewrite not working in production server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, production

I get the following error while setting up mode_rewrite on the production server:

> *404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

I have index.php outside the application folder and so I set the path to `$application_folder` & `$system_path` accordingly.

My folder structure:

```
  folder_A:
    folder_A1:
      index.php
      js
      css
    folder_A2:
      application
      system
```

Here is the .htaccess, in folder_A1

```
RewriteEngine on<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have given `$config['index_page'] = ''`;

And I have tried RewriteBase to '/' as well as 'path/to/app' but in vain.

Could you please find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, your CI folder structure should be something like this to work with that mod_rewrite:

```
root/.htaccess
root/index.php
root/assets/js
root/assets/css
root/assets/img

root/application
root/system
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have a privilege to configure rewrite rule in .htaccess file? I have exactly the same rule in my .htaccess for my CI application, and it's working. Do you have a line something like `AllowOverride ALL` in your apache config file?

Answer (score 0):

change `.htaccess` file content as below:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

Require all denied

Deny from all